# Shapefiles and attributes from ArcGIS Pro missing in ArcMap?

Tags: line, arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, xyz

I have data that is a series of digitised polylines that due to issues with maintaining the Z component have been exported (from another software package) as XYZ points in .csv format.
Using ArcGIS Pro i have then converted these to polylines and in Pro i can see a full attribute table as seen here.

[image: arcPRO screenshot]

When i either export to featuredatabase or shapefile all my attributes are lost... and i gain one i dont want or need!

[image]

Is there a way to maintain the data that i want in the resulting file?

I need a number of the attributes to be able to colour\sort\query the data later.
I have attempted the same thing in ArcMap and QGIS, i have tried converting to featuredatabase and shape, but whatever i do i cannot keep my data how i want it?

Comment: Did you save the points as a shapefile before working with them? This sometimes solves data loss/errors.

Comment: Your X,Y,Z values should still be part of the Polyline. Simply, Start Editing in ArcMap, open Edit Sketch Properties in Edit Vertices. Unfortunately, you can only view a single feature at a time.

Comment: What are the detailed steps that you performed in your workflow that produced this result?  Starting with when you opened ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: My workflow was> export data from source as XYZ points in .csv.>add csv to workspace in ArcGISpro > display XY(Z) data (produces a shapefile of the data) > run Data Management Tool 'Points to Line'. this results in a shapefile of my data with polylines that preserve the Z component as i wanted. Also in Pro I can see and utilise all the attributes  just as they were in the .csv (and shown in the first screenshot). Of course there are slight problems like repeated fields and XYZ coordinates that i think now just represent the first point..

Comment: So i have a number of files like this that i need to edit (remove duplicates and the like) and then merge into a single file. As i am new to Pro i have been opening these files in ArcMap and all the attirbutes are gone. if i export them to a new shapefile and open in Pro, all the attributes are gone (screenshot 2). This is my issue: how to ensure that all my data remains attatched to the file no matter what. After all it is important data... why throw it away?